# Увеличить значение переменной оставив ноль перед числом

Tags: php

Народ подскажите, как мне увеличить значение переменной оставив ноль "0" перед числом? вот наглядный пример:

```
<?php
    $i = 01;
    $i++;
    echo $i; //должно вывести "02"
 ?>
```

и вот еще пример:

```
 <?php
 for($i="01";$i!="13";$i++;){
 echo $i; //в конечном итоге должно вывести: 08 09 10 11 12
 }
```

вся проблема в том что после таких операций ноль "0" пропадает. что посоветуете? может printf()?

Comment: sprintf/printf

Comment: @eicto да подрузамевал, но как не додумался, может подскажете?

Comment: @igolka97, вам уже подсказли. Осталось открыть правильный сайт и [почитать об вышеупомянутых функциях](http://ua1.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++){
    echo sprintf("%1$02d", $i).'<br>';
}
```

Оно?

Comment: пока я писал сам себе ответ вы тоже успели его написать. вот и отмечу вашь вопрос как правильный чтобы закрыть тему

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ, но без помощи [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto) не справился бы
вот как правильно:

```
<?php
for($i="01";$i!="13";$i++;){
echo sprintf("%02d", $i); //в конечном итоге должно вывести: 08 09 10 11 12
}
?>
```